# Clash of Clans account set up

Tags: clash-of-clans

I made a clash of clans account on my android device using my brothers Google+ account. I got a new phone and when I go to try to get my village on the new device its says would you like to load "Kevin village" (my brothers village). I want to be able to get my village on there without having to start over. I tried making a new account and I did not help at all. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you actually link your clan to his Google+ account (by going to settings)? It's not done automatically, and only one village can be linked to a Google+ account. If your brother later linked his village to the same Google+ account, then your village will no longer be linked to it.

The only way to get your existing village back is if it's still on your brother's Android device. If you still have access to it, you can link it to your own Google+ account or use the "Link a device" option in the settings to get it onto your own phone.

If you don't have access to the village anymore, and using the Google+ account that it was supposedly linked to doesn't load your village, then the only way to get it back is to [contact Supercell directly](https://gamesupport.supercell.net/hc/en-us/articles/421502-I-ve-lost-my-village-Can-I-get-it-back-).

> You can submit a help request by sending a message from the game on your device. To send an in-game message, tap the in-game settings icon, select "Help and Feedback", and then tap "Report an Issue". That will assure we have all the necessary data to make the recovering process as quick as possible.
>
> Please include the following information in the message, so that we can locate your village:
>
> - Exact name of the two villages
> - Exact level of the two villages
> - Exact Town Hall level of the two villages
> - Exact clan name of the two villages
>
> Please note that the information is required for both the lost village, and the village that you currently have on your device.

I would recommend doing this from you brother's phone as the device information will help them locate the lost village more easily.

If for some reason you can't use the "Report an Issue" option, there's also the option to send an email to clashofclans.android@supercell.net, though it is generally recommended to use the first method if available.